# Entity Relationship Query and Full Text Search

Tags: elasticsearch, architecture, opensearch

I have a doubt if only with Elasticsearch or Opensearch I can model the proposal below:
I have an index of products, we use it in a marketplace for people to carry out searches and purchases.
Today I have a new requirement which is to allow affiliates to conduct surveys on their products.
Affiliates are people who sell the real owner's product and earn commissions per sale.

Therefore, a product that has 1 owner can have hundreds of affiliates.

Today our index does not contain affiliates and I thought of creating a separate index because we have many affiliates in the base. In this index, we could have the affiliate's code and an array of products he has an affiliation with, but that doesn't seem healthy in terms of performance, as the array would be huge.

Another study was using the parent-join query but I also saw performance issues related to it.

I would like to know from the community if anyone has any experience or suggestions for this modeling that has relationships and allows full text search.

I'm already thinking that for this scenario elasticsearch is not able to solve the whole problem or at least it would be part of a solution that involves another technology.

Any opinion will be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

There's another option you haven't cited, which is **denormalization**. Your approach of creating a new index for this is probably the right one, but instead of having one document per affiliate with an array of products, that index should have **one document per product sold by an affiliate**.

That way your documents stay lean and it's still easy to query the index as the query would contain one constraint for selecting only the documents for a given affiliate who runs the survey and then other constraints and or aggregations on products, dates, etc.

If a new product is sold by an affiliate, just create a new document for that affiliate/product pair.

If a quantity of a given product has been sold via an affiliate, update the quantity sold in the specific affiliate/product document.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I really missed that possibility. I think it was misunderstood but the index will not be a record of product sales per affiliate. It will only be a register of affiliates and their products. A doubt regarding data synchronism, if there is an update in several documents (reason: the name of the product has been changed) can you tell me if it would have a high cost since this product exists in several documents of affiliates?

Comment: In an update event in this suggested modeling I just thought that update_by_query would solve it since I can define batchs.

Comment: _update_by_query allows you to easily update all documents for a given product, indeed